# Rxjs BehaviorSubject Subscription save last value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using RxJS BehaviorSubject to listen event in a component, when i reload browser, my subscription saved the last value, Why and how to when reload the browser, my subscription doesn't save the old value or don't auto execute function ?

```
export class TkComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
     this.subscription = this.myService.navItem$.subscribe(
          item => {
            console.log(item ); //<=== when reload old value saved
            this.getChildItems(item)
          }
        )
      }
    }
 @Injectable()
    export class myService{
     private _navItemSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
     navItem$ = this._navItemSource.asObservable();
     changeNav(item) {
        this._navItemSource.next(item);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. Are you saying you want the stored value in the `BehaviorSubject` to persist between reloads (Ctrl + R) on the browser?

Comment: when browser reloaded, subscribe event fire with old value, i don't want that

Comment: After your browser reloads, it will fire the initial value, 0. It doesn't care if you changed that value before reloading. The application got restarted, so you get the initial value (in your case 0). If you want to keep the value between reloads, you have to save it somewhere (ie: localstorage or database) and use that as the initial value instead of hardcoding that initial value to 0.